# How to push values of custom attributes to Parse database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

Despite the fact that the Parse.User class is supposed to be an extension of the Object class, I am not able to see updates to the record on the Parse data browser. Is this perhaps because calling `Parse.User.current()` is not actually a call to the database?

```
.controller('SignAddrCtrl', ['$scope','$state','geocode','$rootScope','Address',
    function($scope, $state, geocode, $rootScope, Address) {

    $scope.address = {
        userId: {"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":$rootScope.user.id}
    };

    $scope.create = function() {
        geocode.getCoords($scope.address.address1, $scope.address.zipCode)
        .success(function(data) {

            var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            var lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

            $scope.address.location = {
                "__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":lat,"longitude":lng
            };

            Address.create($scope.address)
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data.objectId); // this works
                var activeAddress = {
                    "__type":"Pointer", "className":"Address", "objectId":data.objectId
                }
                 // HERE IS THE ISSUE
                Parse.User.current().set('activeAddress',activeAddress);
                Parse.User.current().get('activeAddress'); // this works

            });

        });
    };
}])
```

What would be the best way to to perform update operations on my User class for custom attributes?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update an object with the latest data from the database, you should fetch it.

```
myObject.fetch({
  success: function(myObject) {
    // Fetch successful
  },
  error: function(myObject, error) {
    // Error handling
  }
});
```